# Need Generic code for multiple divs and grids using javascript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have table with 4 rows and 4 columns and in the last cell of each row, I have a textbox and a button, on clicking of the button a grid with check-boxes and items should show-up. if the relevant checkbox is selected, the label/name of the item should be displayed inside the textbox of the row. I have hardcoded as per requirement. But I will be getting the grid data from a xml file. 
Assuming that I will have 100 to 1000 rows in the main table, I need generic javascript or jquery code for the grid data for each row dynamically please. (Note: grid data will not be same for each row and will be getting from a xml file, so I have to append check boxes in each row of xml data).

The code I wrote can be found in

http://jsfiddle.net/mdiahmed/6se6jmrc/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#c1').on('click', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.cp1').css( 'position', 'absolute' );
        $('.cp1').css( 'top', e.pageY-2 );
        $('.cp1').css( 'left', e.pageX+24 );
        $('.cp1').toggle("slide");
        $('#b1').attr('src','images/ball_red.gif');
        $('.cp2,.cp3,.cp4').hide();
        $('#b2,#b3,#b4').attr('src','images/ball_green.gif');
    });
}); 

$(".checkbox").on("change", function() {
    var companies = [];
    $('.checkbox:checked').each(function() {        
        var companiesTypes = $(this).next().text();
        companies.push(companiesTypes);
    });
    $(".inserdata").val(companies.join(", "));
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#c2').on('click', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.cp2').css( 'position', 'absolute' );
        $('.cp2').css( 'top', e.pageY-2 );
        $('.cp2').css( 'left', e.pageX+24 );
        $('.cp2').toggle("slide");
        $('#b2').attr('src','images/ball_red.gif');
        $('.cp1,.cp3,.cp4').hide();
        $('#b1,#b3,#b4').attr('src','images/ball_green.gif');
    });
});

$(".checkbox1").on("change", function() {
    var companies1 = [];
    $('.checkbox1:checked').each(function() {        
        var companies1Types = $(this).next().text();
        companies1.push(companies1Types);
    });
    $(".data2insert").val(companies1.join(", "));
});
```

and so on for rows of main table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use `data-id` attribute with different value for each row and make a generic jquery script based on the `data-id` value.

The first step is changing your table rows to something like below

```
<tr align="center">
    ...
    ...
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="text1" class="inputField datainsert" data-id="1" size="30" />
        <div style="float:right;" id="c1" class="imgWrapper" data-id="1">
            <img src="images/ball_green.gif" id="b1" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
    ...
    ...
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="text2" class="inputField datainsert" data-id="2" size="30" />
        <div style="float:right" id="c2" class="imgWrapper" data-id="2">
            <img src="images/ball_green.gif" id="b2" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

For each table row, the textbox in the last column has `datainsert` class and different `data-id` value, and the div that wraps the image has `imgWrapper` class and different `data-id` value. Based on the code above, the `data-id` value for the first row is 1, the second row is 2, and so on.

The next step is changing the divs that contain the checkboxes. Make sure all of those divs have the same class (`cp`) and each div has different `data-id` value. The checkboxes also need to have the same class (`checkbox`).

```
<div class="cp" data-id="1" style="display:none; border:1px #000; border-style:solid; width:300px; float:left;">
    <table class="checkboxlist_list">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox ABC" name="keys" id="ABC" value="150" />
                <label for="ABC">ABC company</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox Dufry" name="DEF" id="DEF" value="150" />
                <label for="DEF">DEF COMPANY</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox ADF" name="ADF" id="ADF" value="150" />
                <label for="ADF">ADF COMPANY</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox DBA" name="DBA" id="DBA" value="150" />
                <label for="DBA">DBA COMPANY</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox DPDBA" name="DPDBA" id="DPDBA" value="150" />
                <label for="DPDBA">DPDBA COMPNAY</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="cp" data-id="2" id="companyList2" style="display:none; border:1px #000; border-style:solid; width:300px; float:left;">
    <table class="checkboxlist_list">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox CAM" name="CAM" id="CAM" value="150" />
                <label for="CAM">CAM COMPANY</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox CAN" name="CAN" id="CAN" value="150" />
                <label for="CAN">CAM COMPANY</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox CEI2" name="CEI2" id="CEI2" value="150" />
                <label for="CEI2">CEI - Flagship</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox CEI3" name="CEI3" id="CEI3" value="150" />
                <label for="CEI3">CEI COMPANY</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox CEI5" name="CEI5" id="CEI5" value="150" />
                <label for="CEI5">CEI - Grand LTD</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox CEI7" name="CEI7" id="CEI7" value="150" />
                <label for="CEI7">CEI - Honda</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The last step is changing the jquery script, see the code below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.imgWrapper').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.cp[data-id=' + $(this).data('id') + ']').css('position', 'absolute');
        $('.cp[data-id=' + $(this).data('id') + ']').css('top', e.pageY - 2);
        $('.cp[data-id=' + $(this).data('id') + ']').css('left', e.pageX + 24);
        $('.cp[data-id=' + $(this).data('id') + ']').toggle("slide");
        $('.cp[data-id=' + $(this).data('id') + ']  img').attr('src', 'images/ball_red.gif');
        $('.cp[data-id!=' + $(this).data('id') + ']').hide();
        $('.cp[data-id!=' + $(this).data('id') + ']  img').attr('src', 'images/ball_green.gif');
    });
});
$(".checkbox").on("change", function () {
    var companies = [];
    $('.cp[data-id=' + $(this).closest('.cp').data('id') + '] .checkbox:checked').each(function () {
        var companiesTypes = $(this).next().text();
        companies.push(companiesTypes);
    });
    $(".datainsert[data-id=" + $(this).closest('.cp').data('id') + "]").val(companies.join(", "));
});
```

The click event of `.imgWrapper` div for all rows will be handled in `$('.imgWrapper').on('click'`, which selects the correct `.cp` divs according to the `data-id` value of the clicked `.imgWrapper` div using [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [Attribute Not Equal Selector [name!="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/).

The click event of all checkboxes will be handled in `$(".checkbox").on("change"`, which inserts the text of the selected checkboxes in the same `.cp` div to the `.datainsert` textbox that has the same `data-id` value as the parent `.cp` div of the clicked checkbox.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/oh6eeh7s/